# Appearing With Effect, When Showing Window A Second Time

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I need to know the reason (and possible workarounds) for a strange behavior in Windows 7.
I have Form1 with a button on it and also a second form called Form2. In button's click handler I've:

```
Form2.Show;
```

After running my program, the first time I click on the button, my Form2 appears with a nice fade-in effect  (sorry, I don't know the exact effect name in Windows 7. Tell me if you know!). OK. I close `Form2` and click the button again. This time `Form2` appears with no effect at all.

I want my Form2 to appear with that effect every time I click on the button. To be more specific, I need the main form of a real application to appear when user clicks on a tray icon. The first time clicking on the tray icon shows the window with animation, but second time it doesn't. How can I solve that?

Comment: OT: By using [`AnimateWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632669(v=vs.85).aspx) function you can get even better effects.

Comment: "Any ideas?" isn't a very specific question. I've posted an answer, but you should [edit] to ask something more clear. "I want to write a program to do something. I wrote this line of code. It works the first time, but not after. Any ideas?" isn't really a question.

Comment: @KenWhite, I do apologize for any confusion caused. I edited my question. My problem still persists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows shows that animation the first time a window is shown. So all you need to do is make sure that every time your form is shown, the associated window is being shown for the first time.

You could destroy the form when it closes and create a new instance when you need to show it again. However, that may be inconvenient for you depending on how your form manages state. Judging from your edit and comments, you cannot afford to destroy the form when you close it. Instead you would need to force a new window to be created for your form, each time you show it.

For example, add a call to `DestroyHandle` in the `OnClose` event of the form. Or make a call to `RecreateWnd` immediately before you show the window. Note that the latter will involve making the protected method `RecreateWnd` visible to whoever calls `Show` on the form.

Comment: I called RecreateWnd in FormClose event of Form2. But it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Works fine here. I added some more details to try and help you do it right. But what I state is correct. The animation you want is, by default, shown once only in the lifetime of a window. So all you need to do is make sure that each time your form shows, it is the first time that the associated window is shown.

Comment: When I say "works fine" I don't mean calling RecreateWnd in the OnClose event. That doesn't work. Calling DestroyWnd from there as I describe in the answer.

Comment: Thanks David. Please read my edited question. Can I call DestroyWnd on my main form?

Comment: Yes you can. Just call it at the point where you call `Hide` on the main form.

Comment: And what to call when I want to show it again? Just MainForm.Show?

Comment: But I don't want to fire oncreate event of my mainform, every time I show it.

Comment: Nobody said anything at all about firing `OnCreate`. That happens when the form is created. It's completely unrelated to window creation. Perhaps the problem is that I have assumed that you know the difference between windows and forms, and understand the VCL on-demand window creation policy. Do I need to explain that to you?

Comment: I really thank you for being so informative. Delphi docs recommend DestroyHandle instead of DestroyWnd. Do you know why?

Comment: You are right. Call `DestroyHandle` rather than `DestroyWnd` as described by the docs.

Answer (score 3):

Remove your `Form2` from the auto-create list. (`Project->Options->Forms`, click `Form2` in the left pane, and click the button labeled `>` to move it to the right side.)

Change your `ButtonClick` handler:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  TempFrm: TForm2;
begin
  TempFrm := TForm2.Create(nil);
  TempForm.Show;
end;
```

Add a `FormClose` event to `TForm2` (while you're at it, delete the global `Form2: TForm2;` variable just above the `implementation` clause, so you don't use it again by mistake)::

```
procedure TForm2.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := caFree;
end;
```

As a note: You should go to `Tools->Options->VCL Designer`, and **uncheck** `Auto create forms and data modules` in the `Module creation options` at the bottom. Auto-creating forms is almost always a bad idea; the only thing I ever allow to be auto-create (other than the main form) is any `TDataModule` that needs to be available immediately, and I move it to the top of the auto-create list you saw in the first paragraph so that it's created before the main form.

Comment: I knew I could prevent forms from being auto-created, and create them just before I need to show them. But, the problem is that, in my real application, even the main form is closed, and only is shown by clicking a tray icon. So the first time I click on the tray icon, the animation works. But not the second time. What to do with that?!